# NextJs 13 / Prisma issues rendering page with data

Tags: postgresql, prisma, next.js13

I'm still learning things so please bear with me.
Using Next 13.4.4
Set up a postgres database in Vercel
Created an api in app `src/pages/users` as follows

```
import { prisma } from '@/lib/prisma';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    const users = await prisma.users.findMany();
    res.json(users );
  }
}
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/api/users` I can see my data so based on my limited knowledge that's ok

This is what my page looks like (`app/users/page.tsx`)

```
'use client';

import { User} from '@prisma/client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('api/users');
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }
  return res.json();
}

export default async function UsersPage() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then((users) => {
      setUsers(users);
      console.log(users);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>List Users</h1>
      <ul>
        {users &&
          users.map((user: User) => (
            <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Now I have 2 (separate I believe?) issues

1. When I go to `http://localhost:3000/users` I can see the users been retrieved using Dev Tools.  However they dont show up in the page in the list I'm rendering  (I probably have to go back to the tutorials I've been skimming over lately)
2. When I deploy (vercel) and browse to the page I get ... no way, I'm lying.  Just checked and I get the same issue as local...Can swear it been saying `PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser`.  Confused now

And if anyone would mind crtisizing my code, I'm open to any constructive critic. Things are so different from Angular where I came from (though can't call myself an expert there either)

Comment: One problem was the component was marked as async (from trying things earlier)  Solved the issue re not showing the data.  I will try @Dmitrii Zolotuhin's advise tonight

Answer (score 1):

1. `setProviders` to `setUsers`
2. `PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser`

Possible the issue is:

```
'use client';
import { User} from '@prisma/client';
```

This may pull `@prisma/client` into bundle.

you can try to import only type

```
'use client';
import type { User} from '@prisma/client';
```

or do not import anything from `@prisma/client` inside client component.